# Recurrent pain in the abdominal area after workout

Tags: bodybuilding, pain

I often get a very localized pain in the right side of my abdomen after working out (doesn't seem to matter which muscle group was worked). The area becomes sensitive for days, forcing me to stop weight lifting in the meantime.

Is that a common symptom among bodybuilders and if so what's the typical cause? (I'm in the UK so a GP won't do anything except prescribe paracetamol)

Comment: Sorry, but we can't diagnose existing pain problems here. You're gonna have to go see a doctor. Or if you're unhappy with your doctor's recommendation, see another one. Regardless of how you feel about the quality of the doctors, the Internet is no replacement.